# How to express change as a percentage where lower is better?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Let's say I'm trying to make a web page load faster.  Before, it would take 10 seconds to load a page.  After some system upgrades, the web page takes 1 second to load.

I'd like to tell the client that

> the web page has improved it's render speed by Y percent.

I'm not sure how to solve for `Y` so that my English expression conveys the appropriate message.  Is it `Y = 100%(10/1)`?  So in this case, I've improved the web page render speed by 1000%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render time has decreased by $90\%$. The amount of decrease is $10-1 = 9 $ seconds. As a percentage of the original $10$ seconds, this is $\frac{9}{10} \times 100\%=90\%$.